# Error casting datatype to HashMap: org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Tags: scala, hadoop, parquet, avro

I'm trying to read a parquet file with fields `domainId` and `entityId`.

However, it's giving me this error when it tries to put the values into `HashMap`:

`org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap`

```
  def read(path: String): Seq[Map[String, String]] = {
    val inputFile = HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new Path("/Users/MyUser/TEST/test-compression/part-test-b67081e8-e829-421d-test-test.c000.snappy.parquet"), configs)
    val reader = AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](inputFile).build()

    val records = new ListBuffer[Map[String, String]]()

    var i = Option(reader.read)
    while (i.isDefined) {
      val featureHashMap = i.get.get("domainId").asInstanceOf[java.util.HashMap[Utf8, Utf8]]
      records += featureHashMap
        .asScala
        .map(i => {
          (i._1.toString, i._2.toString)
        })
        .toMap

      i = Option(reader.read)
    }

    records
  }
```

I tried changing `Utf8` to `String` (`java.util.HashMap[String, String]`)but still getting the same error.

Is there anything I can do to get `HashMap` to accept `Utf8`?

Comment: That error looks like `get("domainId")` already returns an instance of `UTF8`. Did you mean `i.get.asInstanceOf[java.util.HashMap[Utf8, Utf8]]` or did you try to just get the "domain id" (which seems to be a single value) as an instance of UTF8?

Answer (score 0):

> org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

This means that the `asInstanceOf` call cannot turn a `Utf8` value into a `HashMap` value because the types aren't compatible. It doesn't matter what are the type parameters of the `HashMap`, it is never going to be a `Utf8`. Even if you fix this particular error, using `asInstanceOf` always has a risk of this kind of failure.

A better solution is to use `match` rather than `asInstanceOf`. One `case` can match on the type that you are expecting and will safely narrow the type to the one that you want. The second `case` can handle other types and provide a default value or error value as appropriate.

In this case it seems that the `domainId` field is just a `Utf8` string, so you may need to process it further to create a `HashMap`, or modify your logic to handle `Utf8` values.